# Spark Age Calculation Interval data Type

Tags: date, apache-spark, intervals

My spark df is made up of columns - `PersonId, DateofBirth`

If I performed following calculation to derive age:
-- `func.current_date() - df.DateOfBirth`

The output is datatype interval with values like

- 45 years 2 days
- 67 years 15 days

Any suggestions how I could extract Year value from Interval datatype?

Comment: if all you need is the number of years, you can just take the difference of the years. `func.year(func.current_date())-func.year(df.DateOfBirth)`

Answer (score 0):

As of now Spark cannot perfrom operations on the Interval Type natively. It can create the Interval type but not perform any further operations on it. See the open JIRA issue: [issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33054](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33054)

With Scala you can do the following using an UDF:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.CalendarInterval

val getPeriod = udf((x: CalendarInterval) => x.extractAsPeriod().getDays())
spark.udf.register("getPeriod", getPeriod)

val testDF = (spark.createDataFrame(List("1970-01-01", "1970-01-02").map(Tuple1(_)))
                   .toDF("DateofBirth")
                   .withColumn("DateofBirth", F.to_date(F.col("DateofBirth"))));
(testDF.withColumn("interval", F.to_date(F.lit("1970-01-10")) - F.col("DateofBirth"))
       .withColumn("diff", getPeriod(F.col("interval")))
       .collect());
```